# limit page links based on the current page

Tags: php, html

I have this code which splits the mysql results into 10 results per page. but I want to edit it so that it limits links based on what the current page is. so on pages 1-10 it only shows page links 1-10 on pages 11-20 it only shows page links 11-20 and so on. how could I achieve this? Thanks.

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) 
  { 
    $page  = $_GET["page"];
  } 
    else 
  { 
    $page=1; 
  };

$start_from = ($page-1) * 10;
$message =  "SELECT * FROM document WHERE email='$_SESSION[email]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from , 10";

              // echo  results

             // make page links for results

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM document WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
  $rs_result = $db->query($sql);
  $total_records = $rs_result->num_rows;
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10);

if($rs_result->num_rows >10) {

    $page = "<p class = 'page'>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
  {
    $page .="<a href='results.html?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
  }
    $page .="</p>";
    echo $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

"SELECT * FROM document WHERE email='$_SESSION[email]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start_from";

Tell me if it works.